# install django in virtualenv python3.4 with linux os in virtualenv

Tags: python, linux, django, debugging, compiler-errors

I am getting this error when importing django inside python :

```
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

I've got a problem when installing django in my web server aws, I made an `alias python = python3` 
so when I am working with python it is python 3.4 which is executing. 
I made a virtual env with it, but when I install django even inside the virtual env, it is installing in the python 2.7 version, not in my virtualenv, and not with the python3 version.

does anyone knows how to make really my python3 as default or how I can install django in the correct folder (python3)

Comment: did you activate the virtualenv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a virtualenv, you need to show that you want to use python3. Do the following:

```
$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3

$ mkvirtualenv name --python=/usr/local/bin/python3
```

then try to install django:

```
$ pip install django
```

Hope it helps